# ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt' - GitBash Windows 10

Tags: git-bash, errno

Hello so I've tried running this `pip install -r requirements.txt` command and the code I used was `winpty python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt` because my previous problem was the `Permission Denied` problem, and when I run `winpty python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt` command the system says says `ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'` in red font color, I've tried this previously with other gits and there was no problem, what could I have done wrong this time? [image: This]
is what Bash looked like when I ran the command I just covered some for things that shows some of my Personal Information please help me out with this, Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you have that `requirements.txt` anywhere in your project.

```
/usr/bin/find . -name "requirements.txt"
```

Try also a `git status` to check if it is not listed as "deleted".

If not, try and generate it

```
winpty pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: I checked and yes, I do have requirements.txt but there is nothing written on it

I dont know how ```/usr/bin/find . -name "requirements.txt"``` works because after i did that it just changed the ``$`` to ``>`` 

did ```git status``` and its not deleted it says
 ```On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        requirements.txt
```
so i tried ```winpty pip freeze > requirements.txt``` and it said
``stdout is not a tty``

Comment: @iXanderM `/usr/bin/find . -name "requirements.txt"` should work, unless you have missed the final `"` at the end of the command.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: @iXanderM if `requirements.txt` is empty,, can you try and generate it with `winpty pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: did it and it says 
```./beep/requirements.txt
./requirements.txt
```
just changed the real name to beep

Comment: did ```winpty pip freeze > requirements.txt``` and ```winpty pip freeze > "requirements.txt"``` both says ```stdout is not a tty```

Comment: @iXanderM Try the `pip install requirements.txt` command in the `beep` folder then (making sure the `requirements.txt` is not empty there)

Comment: there are 2 ``beep`` folders the gitclone aka second ```beep``` was made on the first ```beep``` folder so i cd into the 2nd ``beep`` folder (i.e the gitclone) and did it there, there is nothing in the first ``beep`` folder except for the 2nd ``beep`` folder, in short there is nothing on 2nd folder so i couldn't do anything there

Comment: @iXanderM Too many beep ;) Just make sure to fond a `requirements.txt` which is not empty, and do the `pip install` there.

Comment: ill just delete it and reinstall it in only one folder :)